# Passing Dataframe to function from other file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to import function from other file and pass dataframes to process them.
However I am NOT getting desired output.

File 1 - update_df.py

```
import pandas as pd

def update_df(df1,df2):
    df1 = df1.update(df2)
    print('DF1 is updated')
    return df1
```

File 2 - main.py

```
import pandas as pd
from update_df import update_df

df1 = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\TMP_DATA\\TEST_DATA\\DF_GLOBAL.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\TMP_DATA\\TEST_DATA\\DF_LOAD.csv")

df3 = update_df(df1,df2)
print(df3)
```

Output when I run file 2 -

> DF1 is updated
>
> > None

The dataframe returned from the function is NONE.

Did anyone successfully done this kind of programming?

Thanks
Ady

Comment: DataFrame.update updates the data frame in place and returns `None`, so your function is setting `df1 = None` and then returning it. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

Comment: This is a good opportunity to experiment. Since you are concerned about the return value, include it in your print: `print('DF1 is updated', df3)`. Now you can remove your function's return from the question and focus on why pandas `.update` behaves the way it does.

Answer (score 1):

`df.update()` is an in place operation, it returns `None`. Change the function below.

```py
def update_df(df1,df2):
    df1.update(df2)
    print('DF1 is updated')
    return df1
```

Comment: Still facing same issue.